# What is the Limit as $x^y$ approaches the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I understand that the limit must exist however, I'm not sure how to prove it as this is in 3 dimensions. It is easy in $2D$ because we can approach a point from both sides but here, I can't show an approach along infinitely many paths that cross through the origin and substitute these into my function. How do I got about proving a limit exists in $3D$.

Comment: You are in two dimensions. One dimension with the two sides is easy.

Comment: See my answer to the Mathematics Educators StackExchange question [Multivariable limits](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1865/multivariable-limits).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the dimensions of the domain of a function with the dimensions of its graph. The function $x^y$ only has 2 independent variables so it only makes sense to talk about its limit in 2 dimensions. Its graph $z = x^y$ is 3 dimensional, but that is just a visual representation of the function.

That aside, the limit of $x^y$ as both $x$ and $y$ go to zero depends on the path as you approach the origin, so it is usually considered to be undefined. You can make the function approach any chosen value by simply approaching along a path of $x^y = constant$.